# list items from all child menus(SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have a table of menu, id, title, parent_id

I have attached some content fields to the most bottom level of menus(lets say id = 50), then what if I click on the top parent of that tree menu(id = 1), i want it to display the content that is attached to the child menu(doesn't matter how deep), so I guess that I need to loop through the parents, can you help me with the logic of this?

### The Controller:

```
    $data['query'] = $this->item_model->getByType($menu_id);
```

### The Model:

```
function getByType($menu_id) {
    if($menu_id) {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('menus', array('id' => $menu_id));
        $parent_id = $q->row()->parent_id;
    }else{
        return;
    }
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->where('menu_id', $menu_id);
    $this->db->or_where('menu_id', $parent_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

so by now I only get the items if some menu if I clicked on his parent(2 level), but how to make it infinite level of deep?, I guess that here I need to put in a loop the `or_where`, can you help me with that?

Comment: in other words When i click on some parent menu i want it do display all the content that is attached to his children menus, no matter of deep level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmz... [Recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion)!

```
function getChildrenAttachments($menu_id) {
    // invalid menu id
    if(!$menu_id) return;
    // get all rows with this parent id
    $query = $this->db->get_where('menus', array('parent_id' => $menu_id));
    // result will hold all the attachments
    $result = array();
    // loop through results
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        // does this row have an attachment?
        if($row->attachment!='') {
            $result[] = $row->attachment;
        }
        // add all children attachments
        $result = array_merge($result, getChildrenAttachments($row->id));
    }
    // return result set
    return $result
}
```

This implementation does not take into account the current `menu_id` actually having an attachment. You can create a new function that takes into account that `getAttachmentsForTree()` which checks the current id, then then passes the id to `getChildrenAttachments()`...

P.S. I have not run the code, so I'm sorry for any possible issues with the code. It's just an example on how you can use recursion to your advantage in this scenario.

Comment: I think the line `$result += getChildrenAttachments($row->id);` wont work because of the `+=`, better is: `$result = array_merge($result, getChildrenAttachments($row->id));`

Comment: @Sven that's wrong, `+=` is append not merge, `array_merge` would be wrong, as overwrites would occur on same keys

Comment: Didn't knew that the `+=` is array append. Learned something new then :) +1

Comment: @Sven Drank Coffee! sorry for the misinformation, You are right! Updated my comment accordingly... I'd -1 me if I could :| If keys are numeric, array_merge appends... /shame

Comment: You updated the answer so the +1 stays :) Thx for clearing it up.